# android change imageview programmatically

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am making an android app where the same imageview is displayed every time the user enters a value. but I want the imageview to be changed every time the user enters a value. I wrote a code to do this but the problem is after the first image is displayed I face black screen and it takes me to the first page in the app, it doesn't crash just shows black screen.

here is the imageview code in xml file:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageSuccess"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />
```

and here where I changed the imageview in java file:

```
  ImageView myImage= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageSuccess);    

   if(userVlue.equals("SCHOOL")){

        myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);    
    }
    else if(userVlue.equals("CAR")){
        myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);    
    }
   else if(userVlue.equals("TOY")){
       myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3); 
    }
```

Comment: can you share your logcat response

Comment: @Deepanshu Gandhi I don't test the app using the emulator I test it on my phone, but I will try to run it in the emulator and give you the logcat response.

Comment: Because in XML file you declared the default src is "image1", So, this may make your problem. Try to remove default src, or change it by "android:background". You can check if image1 is shown, then no need to setImageResource(image1).

Comment: default src is not a problem, I just tested it

Comment: You can also log an app running on your phone, just gotta leave it connected to the pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution finally, the black screen appeared because the images were only in the drawable file, so I needed to add the images in all drawbridge folders such as drawable-ldp, drawable-ldpi etc...., so that the app can work in different phone sizes.

Answer (score 1):

One of myImage or userVlue is not set properly and probably is null.
Debug and share logs. Your partcular activity is getting distroyed probably because of nullpointexception hence returning to main activity in backtrack.

I tried with a sample app and your logic is working perfectly.

You are handling user action on some UI element, when you do findViewById, cotext is that UI element, so this method searches ImageSuccess in children of it. Try giving page layout as rootlayout and do rootlayout.findViewById("ImageSuccess");

Comment: @nitish515, In user2420263 question, the "if else" code is correct, and his code did not setBackground null so if userValue is did not in "if, else" -> the default source or old background will be shown. In addition, the app did not crashed -> the myImage will not null.